# Rails 4 Strong Parameters with delegate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, strong-parameters

I am trying to receive the parameters as being from Celeb model and delegate the right ones to user:

```
class Celeb < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :user, as: :role, dependent: :destroy

  delegate :name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name=, :username=, :email=, :password=, :password_confirmation=, to: :user
end
```

In controller:

```
def create
    @celeb = mount_celeb()
    @celeb.assign_attributes celeb_params
    ...

  end

def celeb_params
    params.require(:celeb).permit(:email, :username, :name, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

def mount_celeb
    celeb = Celeb.new
    celeb.build_user
    celeb
  end
```

But the associated user remains empty with no fields assigned. Is there a way to achieve this using strong parameters?

Comment: I see no reason why it would fail, you sure you receive the proper params in your controller?

Comment: It was my fault, I was debugging with byebug and it failed, but in a real request it worked, just needed to refresh to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code in my question works as expected. The problem was that the debugging mode( byebug ) somehow was not reflecting my last changes.

The reason I did that way is because I am creating an API so it's a better idea to abstract nested attributes from documentation( It would be bad to ask the clients to send "user_attributes" in every request)